# Grafana Cloud Cors error - Cors not updating in grafana

Tags: reactjs

I added grafana to my react app

[image]

But i get the error:

```
alkolas.no/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://faro-collector-prod-eu-north-0.grafana.net/collect/b357066b0ea3f785921bb3d11314a597'
from origin 'https://alkolas.no' 
has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource.
If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

even after setting cors policy in grafana:

[image]

Comment: Grafana != Grafana Faro